# Cannot start svn server

Tags: linux, svn

SVN server goes down with linux machine restart but it is not able to start. When executing any SVNSERVE command it is showing an error 'Bus error'.
There is no svnserver currently running on machine and all permission is unaffected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't thank me... I didn't do it...

Comment: @twalberg - that information was really helpful :P.
Anyway I reinstalled SVN its working fine... But couldn't debug the issue :(